# How to unlock Kwalletmanager KDE4 with kwalletmanager5 KDE5?

Tags: kde, opensuse, kde5, kwallet

I am a little lost with kwalletmanager5. I upgraded my system from OpenSuseLEAP42.1 to OpenSuseLEAP42.2 a couple of months ago. With KDE5.

Since I updated my system I have problems with the kwalletmanager, or better the interplay of kwalletmanager5 and the KDE4 version of kwalletmanager.

```
> kwalletmanager --version
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE: 4.14.28
KDE Wallet Manager: 2.0

> kwalletmanager5 --version
kwalletmanager5 16.12.1

> kwalletd --version
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE: 4.14.28
KDE-Dienst für Passwortspeicher: 0.2
```

The main problem I encountered was that the new kwalletmanager5 does not accept a GPG key to encrypt the wallet. This is a problem since I used GPG in KDE4. Now, each time I open the kwalletmanager5, I have to enter first the password for kwalletmanager5 and then for kwalletmanager4.

So I tried to uninstall the KDE4 version of kwalletmanager. Which caused problems with some other applications... Somewhere I read that you need to have installed both versions so that KDE4 applications can use kwalletmanager and KDE5 applications kwalletmanager5.

All in all, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to unlock kwalletmanager with kwalletmanager5?
2. I would like to use GPG-encryption with kwalletmanager5. Is there a way?